# How to encapsulate property collection

Tags: c++, design-patterns, architecture, c++11

i'm developing the people evacuation simulator. At start, it will load a tree-like building structure data (floor/room/wall, etc.) from XML file, load the initial configuration of people, read user-defined moving model parameters and start simulation. E.g. for each man at each model step i need to find all geometry objects near him, and select the closest path to path to exit from the building - as fast as possible.

So, i need to load a clear OOP-way to represent building, where people will move.
I stuck with this (just example):

```
class Aperture
{
   ...
public:
    virtual QRectF extent() = 0;
    virtual QString description() const = 0;
    // other common for all apertures methods

private:
   int m_srcRoomID;
   int m_dstRoomID;
   // other generic aperture properties
};

class Window: Aperture
{
    ...
public:
    virtual void extent() override;
    virtual QString description() override;
    // other overrides

private:
    EGlassType m_glassType;
    bool m_bOpenable;
    // other window-specific properties
};

// and other descendants: Door, CompositeDoor and so on
```

The problem: i want to store all building apertures in one collection as pointers to abstract base `Aperture`, and use only base virtual functions without any casting to derived Apertures.
**BUT**: during evacuation various Aperture properties may change, so i need to modify them in the type-dependent way. I can't make this functionality common and place it to the base class: window haven't closer, antifire door don't afraid of fire - but others do, and so on. May be there is a way (e.g. design pattern) to dynamically store/add/remove these properties? or just avoid subclassing at all, because complete hierarchy of Building items is very compicated and clunky.

Comment: We need more info on what the program is supposed to do. Maybe a class hierarchy is not the ideal candidate here.

Comment: @AlexandreC. Done, i'm updated the question. Sorry if my english is not perfect :/

Answer (score 0):

You could add a virtual function to set the properties in the base class Aperture, like

virtual void update(vector) = 0; or 
virtual void update(...) = 0;

Comment: All properties have different types. You suggest using `vector<QVariant>`, or any other "variant" class?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the entity deciding to close the door needs to know that it can be closed and it should even consider changing that state. Here are some options:

- Make the object decide for itself in a genericish virtual method (something like `Aperture::update`, `Aperture::interactWithFire`, `Aperture::iteractWithPerson` or similar).
- Use the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), i.e. create `virtual Aperture::visit` that will call appropriately overloaded method back on the visitor. That allows you to define interaction methods only for the combination of objects for which it makes sense.
- Use "interfaces", say `IClosable` on anything that can be closed like `Door` and in appropriate place `IClosable * closable = dynamic_cast<IClosable *>(apperture); if(closable) { /* consider whether it should be closed */ }` Actually you'd probably use such interfaces with the visitor pattern too to reduce the number of necessary overloads.

If any, or any combination of this, works for you, the object oriented approach is viable.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer! I forgot to say: my criterias are clean code && nice performance (building can contain a large number of objects). So i'm afraid of using slow `dynamic_cast` operation. Genericish base method is an option, but this can make a "blob" from base class in future. So, the best choice will be some kind of Visitor, e.g. `Hierarchical` one?

Comment: @Axilles: `dynamic_cast` is not that slow. A bit slower than virtual method call, but not by much. Visitor will be cleaner. Hierarchical visitor is suitable, if you have subobjects.

Comment: Ok, i will try Hierarchical visitor. At this moment i see only one serious disadvantage in it - base Visitor interface will be large, because i have many object types.